# Delphi 7 open a cmd when start

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Every time i run my Delphi application, a 'cmd' window open, and some of my users are complaining about this window, saying it crashes their computer, i want to learn WHY this cmd window open, and how make it not open.

My .dpr file is like this

```
... 
Frm05715 in 'fontes\Frm05715.pas' {Form05715}, 
Frm99903 in 'fontes\Frm99903.pas' {Form99903}; 
{$R *.res} 
begin 
Application.Initialize; 
... 
Application.Run;
```

And the cmd window open even before the Application.Initialize, which is the first line that runs

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `Application.Run` in your .Dpr file.  If the cmd window opens before the breakpoint trips, the cmd window is likely being opened in the initialization code of one of your units, which will be straightforward to debug.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57253272/2663863) for how to.

Comment: Yes, it runs before my Application.run. I will try what you said in your answer.

Comment: So, i tried put a breakpoin TProc(P)();. And the cmd window open even before this

Comment: Is your app a console app?

Comment: no, it is a .Exe app

Comment: @GustavoSchmidt There's no such thing as an .exe app. An executable on windows can be either a console app or a GUI app, depending on which subsystem is targeted.

Comment: Sorry, it's a GUI app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I explained in a comment, a way to debug this is to put a breakpoint on `Application.Run` in your .Dpr file.

If the cmd window opens before the breakpoint trips, the cmd window is likely being opened in the initialization code of one of your units, which will be straightforward to debug. You can do that by following the steps in my answer to [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57253272/2663863).

If you check the value of the `Count` variable in `InitUnits` in System.Pas, you might be surprised how high it is, often over 200.  However, you can use a binary search to rapidly identify the guilty unit by putting a breakpoint on the line

```
TProc(P)();
```

and setting its pass count initially to count / 2.  Once you've identified the unit in question, you could use the debugger's `Trace into` (F7) command to identify the code which launches the Cmd window, if that isn't obvious from inspection of the unit's intialization code.

Comment: i did this, and actually got the file which was causing the trouble, and I managed to fix, thank you for the help

Comment: so, i found out there was a file with '{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} ' on the codes, i changed it to {$APPTYPE GUI} and the CMD is not opening anymore